# Product of 2 fibonacci numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, fibonacci

My assignment:

> Given a number, say prod (for product), we search two Fibonacci
>   numbers F(n) and F(n+1) verifying
>
> ```
> F(n) * F(n+1) = prod if F(n) * F(n+1) = prod
> ```
>
> Your function productFib takes an integer (prod) and returns an array:
>
> ```
> [F(n), F(n+1), True] else
> ```
>
> F(m) being the smallest one such as F(m) * F(m+1) > prod
>
> ```
> [F(m), F(m+1), False]
> ```
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> productFib(714) # should return [21, 34, True], 
>             # since F(8) = 21, F(9) = 34 and 714 = 21 * 34
>
> productFib(800) # should return [34, 55, False], 
>             # since F(8) = 21, F(9) = 34, F(10) = 55 and 21 * 34 < 800 < 34 * 55
> ```

My code:

```
def f(i):
    if i == 0 :
        return 0
    if i == 1 :
        return 1
    return f(i-2) + f(i-1)

def productFib(prod):
    i=1
    final1 = 0
    final2 = 0
    while(f(i)*f(i+1) != prod and f(i)*f(i+1) < prod):
        i += 1
        final1 = f(i)
        final2 = f(i+1)
    if(final1*final2 == prod):
        return [final1,final2,True]
    else:
        return [final1,final2,False]
```

I am new to programming; this runs very slow for large numbers.  How can I  reduce the time complexity?

Comment: Recursively calculating `Fib(n)` will have a time complexity of `O(Fib(n))`, since one is added every time. And BTW, `O(Fib(n))` is equal to `O(phi**n)` where `phi=(sqrt(5)+1)/2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def productFib(prod):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while prod > a * b:
        a, b = b, a + b
    return [a, b, prod == a * b]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While this is answering the question, it would be nice, if you could elaborate on how and why this is solving the question.

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost, your **f** function is horridly time-consuming: it computes **f(n)** for low **n** many times.  *Memoize* the function: keep results in a list, and just refer to that list when you compute again.

```
memo = [1, 1]

def f(i):
    global memo

    if i >= len(memo):
        # Compute all f(k) where k < i
        f_of_i = f(i-2) + f(i-1)
        memo.append(f_of_i)

    return memo[i]
```

Note that this sequence still guarantees that you will fill in **memo** in numerical order: f(i-2) is called before f(i-1), and both are called before adding f(i) to the list.

Calling **f(100000000000000)** (10^14) with this returns instantaneously.  I haven't tried it with higher numbers.

**UPDATE**

I ran it with increasing powers of 10.  At 10^1650, it was still printing output at full speed, and I interrupted the run.

**IMPROVEMENT**

You can do even better (for many applications) by directly computing **f(i)** from the closed-form equation:

```
root5 = 5 ** 0.5
phi = (1 + root5) / 2
psi = (1 - root5) / 2

def f(i):
    return int(round((phi ** i - psi ** i) / root5))
```

**MORE IMPROVEMENT**

Directly compute the proper value of **i**.
`f(i) * f(i+1)` is very close to `phi**(2i+1) / 5`.

```
def productFib(prod):
    power = math.log(prod*5) / log_phi
    i = int(round(power-1, 7)/2) + 1
    low  = f(i)
    high = f(i+1)
    # print i, low, high
    answer = [low, high, low*high == prod]
    return answer

print productFib(714)
print productFib(800)
print productFib(100000000000000000)
```

Output:

```
[21, 34, True]
[34, 55, False]
[267914296, 433494437, False]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the performance quite a bit by making use of a generator.

```python
def fib():
    # Generator that yields the last two fibonacci numbers on each iteration.
    # Initialize
    np = 0
    n = 1

    # Loop forever. The main function will break the loop.
    while True:
        # Calculate the next number
        nn = np + n

        # Yield the previous number and the new one.
        yield n, nn

        # Update the generator state.
        np = n
        n = nn

def product_fib(prod):
    # Loop through the generator.
    for f_0, f_1 in fib():
        # If the product is larger or equal to the product return.
        if f_0 * f_1 >= prod:
            # The last element in the list is the resut of the equality check.
            return [f_0, f_1, f_0 * f_1 == prod]


t0 = perf_counter()
res = productFib(8000000000)
t = perf_counter() - t0
print("Original:", t, res)

t0 = perf_counter()
res = product_fib(8000000000)  # 8000000000
t = perf_counter() - t0
print("New:", t, res)
```

The output of this is

```
Original: 0.8113621789962053 [75025, 121393, False]
New: 1.3276992831379175e-05 [75025, 121393, False]
```

**Edit**

If you want a single line. It works, but don't use it, it's not really the most practical solution. The first one is faster anyways.

```
print((lambda prod: (lambda n: next(([a, b, (a * b) == prod] for a, b in ([n.append(n[0] + n[1]), n.pop(0), n][-1] for _ in iter(int, 1)) if (a * b) >= prod)))([0, 1]))(714))
```

Comment: btw. You can import the perf_counter from the time package.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fib` function is recalculating from the bottom every time. You should save values you already know. My python is rusty, but I think this will do it:

```
dict = {}

def f(i):
    if dict.has_key(i):
        return dict[i]
    if i == 0 :
        return 0
    if i == 1 :
    return 1
    sum = f(i-2) + f(i-1)
    dict[i] = sum
    return sum

def productFib(prod):
    i=1
    final1 = 0
    final2 = 0
    while(f(i)*f(i+1) != prod and f(i)*f(i+1) < prod):
        i += 1
        final1 = f(i)
        final2 = f(i+1)
    if(final1*final2 == prod):
        return [final1,final2,True]
    else:
        return [final1,final2,False]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code for your ProductFib function

```
def productFib2(prod):
    i=0
    final1 = f(i)
    final2 = f(i+1)
    while(final1 * final2 < prod):
        i += 1
        final1 = final2
        final2 = f(i+1)
    if(final1*final2 == prod):
        return [final1,final2,True]
    else:
        return [final1,final2,False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of different algorithms that are increasingly optimized (starting with the original algorithm).

**Algorithm 3** uses an **iterative fibonacci with caching** along with **guessing the square root** (which should be between the two multiples of the fibonacci product).

**Timing Results:**

```
Original algorithm:                          4.43634369118898
Algorithm 2 (recursive fib):                 1.5160450420565503
Algorithm 2 (iter fib):                      0.03543769357344395
Algorithm 2 (iter fib + caching):            0.013537414072276377
Algorithm 3 (iter fib + caching + guessing): 0.0017255337946799898
```

---

**Setup:**

```
import timeit

from random import randint
from math import sqrt
from bisect import bisect

cache = [0, 1]
```

**Nth Fibonacci Number Algorithms:**

```
def f(n):
    """Recursive solution: O(2^n)"""
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return f(n-2) + f(n-1)


def ff(n):
    """Iterative solution: O(n)"""
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a


def fff(n):
    """Iterative solution + caching"""
    length = len(cache)
    if n >= length:
        for i in range(length, n+1):
            cache.append(cache[i-1] + cache[i-2])
    return cache[n]
```

**Fibonacci Product Algorithms:**

```
def pf1(prod):
    """Original algorithm."""
    i=1
    final1 = 0
    final2 = 0
    while(f(i)*f(i+1) != prod and f(i)*f(i+1) < prod):
        i += 1
        final1 = f(i)
        final2 = f(i+1)
    if(final1*final2 == prod):
        return [final1,final2,True]
    else:
        return [final1,final2,False]


def pf2(prod, fib_func):
    """Algorithm 2.

    Removes extra logic and duplicate function calls."""
    i = 1
    guess = 0
    while guess < prod:
        final1 = fib_func(i)
        final2 = fib_func(i + 1)
        guess = final1 * final2
        i += 1

    return [final1, final2, guess == prod]


def pf3(prod, fib_func):
    """Algorithm 3.

    Implements square root as a guess."""
    guess = sqrt(prod)  # Numbers will be near square root

    i = 2
    while cache[-1] < guess:
        fff(i)
        i += 1

    insertion_spot = bisect(cache, guess)
    test1 = cache[insertion_spot-1]
    test2 = cache[insertion_spot]

    return [test1, test2, (test1 * test2) == prod]
```

**Testing & Output:**

```
prods = [randint(3, 99999) for _ in range(1000)]  # 1000 random products
print("Original algorithm:                         ", timeit.timeit("for prod in prods: pf1(prod)", number=1, setup="from __main__ import pf1, prods"))
print("Algorithm 2 (recursive fib):                ", timeit.timeit("for prod in prods: pf2(prod, f)", number=1, setup="from __main__ import pf2, prods, f"))
print("Algorithm 2 (iter fib):                     ", timeit.timeit("for prod in prods: pf2(prod, ff)", number=1, setup="from __main__ import pf2, prods, ff"))
print("Algorithm 2 (iter fib + caching):           ", timeit.timeit("for prod in prods: pf2(prod, fff)", number=1, setup="from __main__ import pf2, prods, fff"))
print("Algorithm 3 (iter fib + caching + guessing):", timeit.timeit("for prod in prods: pf3(prod, fff)", number=1, setup="from __main__ import pf3, prods, fff, cache; cache = [0, 1]"))
```

**Helpful Time Complexities of Python "List" object:** https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 0):

Two ways: slow and fast way to do it

Slow:

```py
def productFib(prod):
    i=0
    final1 = f(i)
    final2 = f(i+1)
    while(final1 * final2 < prod):
        i += 1
        final1 = final2 #this is the same as final1 = f(i) again but, the value is already in memory no need to recalc it
        final2 = f(i+1)
    if(final1*final2 == prod):
        return [final1,final2,True]
    else:
        return [final1,final2,False] #if non equivilant product
def f(i): #fib(0) == 0 fib(1) == 1
    if i == 0 :
        return 0
    if i == 1 :
        return 1
    return f(i-2) + f(i-1)
```

output of the product in the while loop:
0
1
2
6
15

Fast:

```py
def productFib(prod):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while prod > a * b:

 1. List item

        a, b = b, a + b #a is equal to b and b is equal to the sum of a and b
    return [a, b, prod == a * b] #return a and b as well as the conditional if a times b is equal to the product
```

You don't need to check if something is apart of the fib series here because we can simply iterate over the series within the while loop without having to call another function recursively
the fib function is defined as: F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) with F(0) = 0 and F(1) = 1. therefore, you can generate this with the algorithm in the while loop above
following that a = 0, b = 1 next a = 1, b = 1 next a = 1, b = 2 next a = 2, b = 3
next a = 3, b = 5 ...

Comment: I will upvote this answer if you do something to correct the "1. List item" line in order to make the Fast method (which works OK) more readable.